# Name and symbol for "direct" multiplication

Tags: terminology

This is a really simple question and I feel pretty stupid for asking it, but what do you call the operation that takes two vectors $(x_1, x_2 ...)$ and $(y_1, y_2 ...)$ and results in a new vector $(x_1 y_1, x_2 y_2 ...)$? And what is the standard symbol for it?

Comment: It is unlikely to be very useful, since it changes when you change basis.

Comment: @GEdgar I find it comes up a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the "entrywise" product. If you treat the vectors as matrices, it's also the [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)).

It's not a common enough product to have a dedicated symbol, but Wikipedia uses $\circ$.